# No debugging symbols found in base_local_planner library

Tags: navigation, ros-diamondback, eclipse, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm new to ROS. At the moment I'm using Eclipse CDT to debug the *move_base* node, more specifically the default local planner (*base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS*). When I start the *move_base* node, Eclipse can apparently find the debugging symbols for all the necessary packages (*navfn*, *costmap_2d*, etc) except for *base_local_planner* (libbase_local_planner.so). Indeed when I run the command "file libbase_local_planner.so" inside gdb, it tells me there's no debug symbol for that library.

I've tried to make sure the "-g" option was actually used to link the library, but I admit I got lost in the cmake files.

However I don't remember changing any linking option anywhere... anyone's got a clue to what may cause the problem? (and are the debugging symbols for this library present in your setup?)

Thanks,
Simon C

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11489/no-debugging-symbols-found-in-base_local_planner-library/) by [SimonC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1206/simonc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The base_local_planner has the build type set to "Release" in the CMakeLists.txt which does not include debug symbols.  Change it to RelWithDebug and recompile to get debugging symbols.  Usually the release type should be commented out in released code to allow the system builder to change the build type for the whole system.  You might want to open a ticket about this for the base_local_planner package.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SimonC](https://answers.ros.org/users/1206/simonc/) on 2011-10-11**:
Thanks that was it! Not sure why I didn't spot the option...!